# Insert ArrayList / Vector into SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, arraylist

I've got a ArrayList or Vector with this structure

```
ArrayList = value1 value2 value3 value4 value5, value1_1 value2_1 value3_1 value4_1 value5_1, [...]
```

up to value1_200 (variable, but in this size).

I want to insert every value in one column. My database structure:

```
value1 VARCHAR, value2 VARCHAR, value3 VARCHAR, value4 VARCHAR, value5 VARCHAR
```

Should I use `BLOB` and how can I insert it into an SQLite DB? (Every value set should be into one row)

Comment: Is there a reason you want one row per value? Sounds more like you want file storage rather than a db with the structure you're talking about...?

Comment: I need to `SELECT` the values with `value1`.
Before I'am inserting values like this: `db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rndTable (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5) VALUES ('value', 'value', 'value', 'value', 'value')");` and need to SELECT like this, because using a listview, `"SELECT value2 FROM stations WHERE value1=" + "'" + value + "'"` (value2 can be changed with value3, value4 and value5)

Comment: It'd make more sense if your data structure was `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>` that way each item in the `ArrayList` was a complete row.

Comment: I can change the structure, thats no problem. I will try to change it. But Hhw I can insert this ArrayList into db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it on my own, converted the `ArrayList` to `String` and inserted it with this method.

```
  int init = 0;
  for(int t = init; t < arr.length; t++){
      Log.i(TAG, "arr["+t+"] = " + arr[t].trim());

    if(r == 1) {
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES ('" + arr[t].trim() + "')");
        id_save = arr[t].trim();
        r++;
    }else if(r == 2) {
        database.execSQL("UPDATE table SET name='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "'");
        name_save = arr[t].trim();
        r++;
    }else if(r == 3) {
        database.execSQL("UPDATE table SET weburl='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "' AND name='" + name_save + "'");
        r++;
    }else if(r == 4) {
        database.execSQL("UPDATE tables SET mainurl='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "' AND name='" + name_save + "'");
        r++;
    }else if(r == 5) {
        database.execSQL("UPDATE table SET logo='" + arr[t].trim() + "' WHERE id='" + id_save + "' AND name='" + name_save + "'");
        r = 1;
    }
```